# MongoDB Locking

Tags: mongodb, nosql, wiredtiger

my mongodb bulk update write is slow using mongo java driver then i was checked mongodb log file and i observed the global and collection level locking is high.
 two different index i modified but still having locking issue.
if you know any one reason pls let me know

MongoDB Log:

2017-10-11T19:04:40.941+0530 I WRITE    [conn1164] update ghana.data_usage_summary query: { MS: "6028150899", MN: 1, CD: 2, CO: 1, DI: 1, MI: 1706, ST: "14000Kbps", VT: "Science_Fiction", SI: 1, AD: 1, PI: 1, YM: 201710 } planSummary: IXSCAN { MS: 1.0, ST: 1.0, YM: -1.0 } update: { $inc: { DY.SU.10: 1, DY.TO.10: 0, DY.FL.10: 0, HR.18.FL.10: 0, WK.FL.1: 0, MO.FL.0: 0, HR.18.SU.10: 1, HR.18.TO.10: 0, WK.SU.1: 1, WK.TO.1: 0, MO.SU.0: 1, MO.TO.0: 0 } } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 numYields:1 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20, w: 20 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 20 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 20 } } } 148ms
2017-10-11T19:04:41.035+0530 I COMMAND  [conn1165] command ghana.$cmd command: update { update: "data_usage_summary", ordered: false, bypassDocumentValidation: true, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:59 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1021, w: 1021 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1021 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1021 } } } protocol:op_query 1046ms
2017-10-11T19:04:41.663+0530 I COMMAND  [conn1166] command ghana.$cmd command: update { update: "data_usage_summary", ordered: false, bypassDocumentValidation: true, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:59 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1032, w: 1032 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1032 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1032 } } } protocol:op_query 1316ms

Thanks
Shankar

Comment: What does "slow" mean?   How big is each doc and how big of a bulk buffer are you using?   How many bytes are you trying to write to what kind of disks?

Comment: Hi Buzz Moschetti Thanks, 1) Slow means: Bulk update is taking more time as per above log one record aprox 148ms to update. 2) Disk is SAS and XFS file system 3) Each record size is avg 4170 bytes   and how to measure bulk buffer ?.